# How to deal with unresolved import 'concrete' issues in RUST

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to RUST, and I am trying to use this concrete library: https://github.com/zama-ai/concrete/tree/master/concrete. I am trying to create a simple "Hello World" in RUST to see if concrete imports correctly. I followed the instructions in the aforementioned link.

Specifically, I:

1. Cloned the GitHub repo.
2. Cd into concrete folder (/concrete/concrete)
3. ran "cargo new play_with_fhe"
4. Updated the "Cargo.toml" file with the new member "play_with_me"

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "concrete",
    "concrete-npe",
    "concrete-core",
    "concrete-csprng",
    "concrete-commons",
    "concrete-tasks",
    "concrete-boolean",
    "play_with_fhe",
]

[profile.bench]
opt-level = 3
debug = true
lto="fat"

[patch.crates-io]
concrete = {path="concrete"}
concrete-npe = {path="concrete-npe"}
concrete-core = {path="concrete-core"}
concrete-csprng = {path="concrete-csprng"}
concrete-commons = {path="concrete-commons"}
concrete-boolean = {path= "concrete-boolean"}
play_with_fhe = {path= "play_with_fhe"}
```

5. Cd into "/concrete/concrete/play_with_fhe" and updated the "Cargo.toml" file with

```
[package]
name = "play_with_fhe"
version = "0.1.11"
authors = ["FHE Curious"]
edition = "2018"
# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
concrete = "^0.1.11"
```

6. Cd into /concrete/concrete/play_with_fhe_/src and created a main.rs file running a simple code:

```
use concrete::*;
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

7. When I try compiling it with rustc main.rs, I get told that:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `concrete`
 --> main.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use concrete::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `concrete`?

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
```

How can I address this issue? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you clone `concrete` repo ??? the readme have even the instruction for new Rust user https://github.com/zama-ai/concrete/tree/master/concrete#use-concrete-in-your-own-project

Comment: be sure to check twice your Cargo.toml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to create your own hello world project, you don't need to clone the repository. You just need to create a project, include concrete as a dependency, and then import it. Those instructions are on the [concrete page](https://github.com/zama-ai/concrete/tree/master/concrete#use-concrete-in-your-own-project) (as Stargateur notes):

```
% cargo new play_with_fhe
% cd play_with_fhe
```

Add `concrete` to your dependencies in Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "play_with_fhe"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
concrete = "^0.1"   # <--- This is the only change you make. The rest is template.
```

Then add `use cargo::*` to the top of your main.rs, and build it:

```
% cargo build
```

This will install everything. For more on Cargo, see [Dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/cargo/deps.html) in Rust By Example.

Note that this package likely won't build correctly unless you're on an x86 architecture. For example, [it won't run on an Apple M1 without Rosetta2.](https://github.com/zama-ai/concrete/issues/65)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did try a directory just for the new project, but the point I was missing was running cargo build. I was just doing "rustc main.rs".